# YouTube API getAvailableQualityLevels() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, safari, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        ql = event.target.getAvailableQualityLevels();
        console.log(ql);
    }
}
```

I want to print the quality array. This **works most of the times in Safari** but not always and it does't work in Chrome nor Firefox. I don't understand why it works some times in Safari and why other times not and why it doesn't work in other browsers?

This is how I call the API

```
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: height,
            width: width,
            videoId: yt_id,
            playerVars: {
            html5: 1,
            wmode: "transparent",
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            rel: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3 //anottations
            },
            events: {
                'onError': onPlayerError,
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens when it "doesn't work"? Are you using the latest version of those browsers?

Comment: yeah the latest versions of each of them on OS X Yosemite. I don't get any errors it just won't print on the console. But what is weird is that it works sometimes on Safari not always. There are many other lines of code in the file. Do you want me to remove those and try again?

Comment: It's worth a shot. Maybe you could include some more debugging statements in your code while you try to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Hey it works perfectly. I commented all the other lines. I will do some debuging now to find the error. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear, hope you're able to find the root of the problem.